# Ошибка ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution' при установке модуля

Tags: python, pip

Всем добрый день. Возник вопрос по поводу командной строки. Ввожу команду:

```
python -m pip install mysql-connector
```

На что вылезает ошибка в командной строке:

```
C:\Users\pp>python -m pip install mysql-connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 96, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._internal.operations.prepare import RequirementPreparer
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions import (
  File "C:\Python3.8.2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions.source import SourceDistribution
ImportError: cannot import name 'SourceDistribution' from 'pip._internal.distributions.source' (C:\Python3.8.2\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\distributions\source\__init__.py)
```

Так возникает с любой библиотекой, которую пытаюсь установить. Как исправить эту ошибку? Заранее большое спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [баг](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7620) pip версии 20.0. Он исправлен в версии 20.0.1.

Скачайте [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) и обновите pip:

```
python get-pip.py
```

Или откатитесь к версии 19.3.1:

```
python get-pip.py pip==19.3.1
```

Перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59848737/7485582) [@phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd)

Comment: возникает ошибка при попытке установки версии 19.3.1: python: can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Откройте терминал в директории, в которой лежит этот файл, или пропишите полный путь до файла.

Comment: Подскажите,пытаюсь сделать как Вы сказали, но безрезультатно

Comment: скриншот в тексте

Comment: `python C:/path/to/file/get-pip.py pip==19.3.1` . Замените путь в команде на путь до скаченного файла.